# Spring Cloud: how to use Feign without registration into Eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

I have a eureka server and some services, they register to the eureka and use a Feign to communicate with each other.

Every of such services is deployed into embedded tomcat container.  Also I have some services which are executed as a demons by scheduled, they shouldn't be into tomcat container, but they also have to use a Feign to get data from some services.

By example I have a monitoring which is executed one time per day and checks some data got from another service by REST. That monitoring don't have to register in eureka cause it doesn't have api for input.

If I put `@EnableFeignClients` without `@EnableEurekaClient`, it won't work, but 
if i put both of these annotations, service will be deployed into tomcat.

How could I do that without tomcat container?

Comment: You still want a eureka client, you just want to disable the registration. That is something different, without the client you also wouldn't be able to detect the services. Add `eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false`, that way it won't be registered.

Comment: won't the app being executed in tomcat container if i just put registerWithEureka=false in config?

i'd like to make simple app which i could execute as `java -jar myapp`.
The app has to get some data through the Feign from a service registered in a Eureka, to do some job and after that shutdown. Do i have to use embedded tomcat for that?
How could i use the Feign + Eureka manually?

Comment: No i t won't... The fact that you use eureka has nothing to do with the fact that it is (or isn't) a tomcat driven application. You can just create a simple app... You don't need to do it manually...

Comment: i've solved my problem. i should'ev exclude spring-boot-starter-web from spring-cloud-starter-eureka. thanks